# Feeling Tilted During Meditation

Tags: meditation-effects, meditation-hindrances

Can anyone enlighten me as why I feels like my body is tilted around 30 degrees to the right during meditation?

This happens around 10-15 minutes after I've started.

I don't do any breathing technique, I just sit still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many specific reasons why this sort of thing happens but generally speaking it's because the body posture is only a conceptual entity in the mind, formed based on individual, momentary experiences. If for whatever reason your physical experiences are out of the ordinary, it is common for them to give rise to erroneous conceptualizations in the mind of how the "body" is situated, as the mind tries to relate the new sensations to old conceptualizations. Feeling like part of your body is bloated, twisted, tilted, or even disappeared are all commonly reported experiences.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

I'd carry on the meditation, see if the tilting disappears or still present but won't be bothersome anymore.

Comment: @Greg yes, not something to be concerned by, though that's a given since nothing is worth clinging to :)